# How to find the latest file in folder using azure data factory v2 (adf)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to read the latest blob file(csv) using azure data factory v2. The file name also contains date(YYYY-MM-DD mm:ss-abcd.csv). I need to read the data from the latest file present and load into table storage. Could you please help me with how to read the latest file using ADF

Comment: I guess, You might have created blob storage for holding input files. To get the latest file to be executed, the simplest solution would be create another folder lets say `Success` and move the file which were get executed to the `Success` folder. So the `input` folder will always be empty once the file gets executed and any new file gets uploaded into `input` folder that will automatically picked up for processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Faiz Rahman and thank you for your question.  The date format you chose has the useful feature of lexicographic sorting matching chronological sorting.  This means, once you have a list of blobs, extracting the date and comparing is all that is needed.

If you have a very large list of blobs, this might not be practical.  In that case, whenever you write a new blob, keep track of it somewhere, say, "maxBlobName.txt", and have pipeline read that to get the name of the most recent file.

Here is some example code for comparing the date portion of your blob names.  To adapt for your purposes, you will need to use GetMetadata activity to fetch the blob names, and some string functions to extract only the date portion of the name for comparison.

```
{
"name": "pipeline9",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "ForEach1",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "init array",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@variables('list')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "isSequential": true,
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "If Condition1",
                        "type": "IfCondition",
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "expression": {
                                "value": "@greater(item(),variables('max'))",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "ifTrueActivities": [
                                {
                                    "name": "write new max",
                                    "type": "SetVariable",
                                    "typeProperties": {
                                        "variableName": "max",
                                        "value": {
                                            "value": "@item()",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "init array",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "list",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@split(pipeline().parameters.input,',')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "input": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "'2019-07-25','2018-06-13','2019'-06-24','2019-08-08','2019-06-23'"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "max": {
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "0001-01-01"
        },
        "list": {
            "type": "Array"
        }
    }
}
```

}